# accessing recources when compiling QT application with Bazel

Tags: c++, qt, bazel

I'm using Bazel to compile a Qt application (https://github.com/bbreslauer/qt-bazel-example) that is using shaders defined in a qrc file.
When I'm trying to access the resource file, it is not available (as I did not connect the qrc file to the compilation).
How can I define the qrc file content in the build?

UPDATE

following the response by @ypnos, I'm trying to add a macro to my qt.bzl file. I would like the macro to recieve a list of files as an argument, create the (temporary) qrc file, and run the rcc command.
I am currently struggling with:

1. running a python script in the bzl file is not as straightforward as I though. It cannot generate a file ("open" is undefined). Is it possible? if yes how (see example below)
2. even with a given qrc file, I cant get the command to work, I guess i'm doing somthing wrong with the command line arguments but I cant find refrence/manual for that

this is what I got so far(my qt.bzl file)

```
...



def qt_resource(name,file_list, **kwargs):
## following doesnt work inside the bzl file:
  # fid = open('%s.qrc' % name, 'w')
  # fid.write("<RCC>\n")
  # fid.write("\t<qresource prefix=\"/%s\">\n" % name)
  # for x in file_list:
  #   fid.write("\t\t<file>%s</file>\n" % x)
  # fid.write("\t</qresource>\n")
  # fid.write("</RCC>\n")
  # fid.close()
  native.genrule(
      name = "%s_res" % name,
      outs = ["rcc_%s.cpp" % name],
      cmd =  "rcc %s.qrc -o $@/rcc_%s.cpp"%(name,name) ,

  )
  srcs = [":rcc_%s.cpp" % name]
  native.cc_library(
      name = name,
      srcs = srcs,
      hdrs = [],
      deps = [],
      **kwargs
  )
```

Comment: You should open a new question, chances are low anybody will read this question as it is old and already answered.

Comment: Also this might help: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/language.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the bazel example that you are using does not come with support for qrc (it only does moc and ui files).[1](https://github.com/bbreslauer/qt-bazel-example/blob/91c888a5663ea1fb640cb54d383a4a67376ff522/tools/build_rules/qt.bzl#L22)

QRC files need to be transformed into C++ sources using `rcc` and then compiled.[2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#compiled-in-resources) The concept is similar to the one of .ui files which are converted to headers.

Maybe you can patch `qt.bzl` to add that functionality.